# я делаю оператор [], который получает индекс. в main не видит оператор []. что я делаю не так?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {

    int index, first;

    cout << "Please enter the first vector (first,second): ";
    cin >> first >> second;
    Vector* v1 = new Vector(first, second);
    cout << "The vector you've entered is: ";
    v1->print();
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Please enter index: ";
    cin >> index;
    cout << v1[index];
    cout << endl;

    delete[] v1;
    return 0;
}




    int& Vector ::operator [] (int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            return *first;
        }
        else if(index == 1){
            return *second;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно разыменовать указатель:

```
cout << (*v1)[index];
```

Либо вызвать оператор как функцию:

```
cout << v1->operator [](index);
```

Comment: `*v1[index]` эквивалентно `*(v1[index])`, возможно Вы имели ввиду `(*v1)[index]`.